# Communicating with a Fragment in a FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an FragmentActivity that has tabbed fragments using the example adapter set forth in `FragmentTabsPager.java` (found in the Android Support v4 samples)

```
private static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
```

I have a menu entry in my FragmentActivity that will let me reload the data inside the fragments at will. Before I implemented the tab interface, I could guarantee that the needed fragment would be loaded in memory. I'd get the Fragment via `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()`, cast it, then call its reload function. Simple enough.

**Is there a way I can communicate with a specific Fragment instance loaded via `FragmentPagerAdapter` from a FragmentActivity?** Using `TabAdapter`'s `getItem()` provided in the sample, I can retreive a *new* instance (via `Fragment.instantiate()`) of my Fragment but not a reference to the one that's currently displayed. That's the one that matters.

**EDIT:** In addition to Plato's answer...
Since all my tabs are of different classes (eg. FooFragment, BarFragment, etc) it's very useful to identify and retrieve an active fragment of a specific type.

```
Object getActiveFragmentOfType(Class<?> cls) {
    List<Fragment> frags = getActiveFragments();
    for(Fragment one : frags) {
        if(cls.isInstance(one)) {
            return one;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then when I want to work on a specific tab/fragment/class I just do something like this

```
Object fooFragmentObject = getActiveFragmentOfType(FooFragment.class);
if(fooFragmentObject != null) {
    // Do something with an active reference to fooFragmentObject that's
    // guaranteed to be castable to FooFragment
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a base class for your fragments so you can add methods to save and get the position the fragment is used for. *(You can do this with an interface which all would implement if you dont want them all to extends the same class)*

So your fragment class would be something like this.

```
    class MyFragment extends SomeFragment{
       public void setPosition(int position){...}
       public int getPosition(){...}
       ......
    }
```

in your `FragmentPagerAdapter` edit the `getItem()` method to save the position within each fragment when you create it.

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        //save the position when you create the Fragment
        fragment.setPosition(position);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Then implement a **getActiveFragments()** method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi)

After that it's simple to create a method to get the current Fragment by using the `getCurrentItem()` method of the `ViewPager` to get the current position.

```
    private MyFragment getCurrentFragment(){
      int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem(); //get current position

      List<MyFragment> fragments = getActiveFragments();
      for(MyFragment one: fragments){
         if (one.getPosition() == position)
           return one;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Let me know how that worked out.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Loaded it up my device and I saw it in action in sync with the last line of Led Zeppelin's Stairway To Heaven (Live 1973).