# How do I iterate through Android Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, iteration

For a week I have been searching and trying but I cannot find a proper solution for the following Android issue. (This is how I see it now and it may be the wrong approach)

We have a MainActivity and 3 Fragments: SingleAnswer, MultipleAnswer and ImageAnswer. The MainActivity retrieves an object with a random amount of questionTypes. The MainActivity uses starts a fragment based on the retrieved object.

How can I iterate through Fragments?

For example: First there is a MultipleAnswer Fragment and a answer is selected by the user. Then the next Fragment has to be loaded...

I don't know if this approach is right or if I have to look for something else than Fragments.

Comment: You can `replace` the fragment depending on the object what you received. You can also use `getFragmentById()` or `getFragmentByTag()` to retrieve the fragment if it is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Someone also faced this problem. At the first glance there does not seem to be a getFragments method.
However you can use a workaround as specified here:

[Is there a way to get references for all currently active fragments in an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi)

Answer (score 0):

it is not real to iterate fragments that was not added, only replace will be good choice or
try to use ViewPager for it with adapter example:  http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html 
in the main activity initialize your adapter like this one :

```
 mContainer = (ViewPager) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.pager_container);
    myPager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    adapter = new MyPager(myPager,new String[]{"R.layout.first","R.layout.second","...."});

myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I see there are some options, thanks