# Android: Back button event in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, fragment

I have a FragmentActivity.
The Activity contains one fragment.
In the fragment, there is a button, when click a imageview will appear (View.VISIBLE) at the center.
I want to have a back button event to check that if the imageview is visible, then hide it, otherwise, continue the default back button event.
As the FragmentActivity and the Fragment is separate class. And there are no onBackPressed() in Fragment. So how can I do it? I want to handle the back event in the Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

When `onBackPressed()` is triggered in Activity, communicate it with the fragment you need, check this link to see how to communicate between fragments and activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // If the fragment is here, let him handle it
    ourFragment.someMethodWeveCreatedToHandleBackPressed();

    // If it was not handled by the method above, then let the super do his usual "back"
    if (!handled){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Activity may contain different fragment. Then how to call the method above one by one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override `onKeyDown` method inside your fragment?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Check you image view visibility
        if(yourImageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
              yourImageView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
              return true; // This line is important to handle the event here and not in the next receiver
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Let me know if it works to you!

Answer (score -2):

Use transaction.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: It won't work because the `ImageView` is inside the same fragment. There is only one fragment.