# How to get currently visible fragment from activity when using holoeverywhere slider addon?

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I want to know how to perform these actions in [holoeverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere):

Get reference to the currently visible and active fragment from the activity when using slider addon in combination with tabber.

Get reference to TabsTabsSwipeFragment from the activity/other fragments and dynamically disable/enable swiping.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21104084/80428

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get currently displayed fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Get a reference to the currently visible and active Fragment from the Activity when using slider addon in combination with tabber:**
>
> You can provide a tag for a Fragment like this:
>
> ```
> sliderMenu.add("tab2", Fragment2.class, SliderMenu.GREEN).setTag("mynavigation-2");
> ```
>
> Also you can get the current page number using:
>
> ```
> sliderMenu.getCurrentPage();
> ```
>
> You have no way of obtaining the current Fragment directly, but you can combine these two methods and find a Fragment via the `FragmentManager`:
>
> ```
> getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mynavigation-" + sliderMenu.getCurrentPage());
> ```
>
> **Get a reference to the `TabsTabsSwipeFragment.java` from the Activity/other Fragments and dynamically disable/enable swiping.
>   In your code:**
>
> ```
> getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mynavigation-2").getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(tagFragmentId);
> ```
>
> In your Activity:
>
> ```
> private int tagFragmentId;
> public void setTagFragmentId(int i) {
>     Log.i(TAG, "fetched setTagFragmentId: " + i);
>     tagFragmentId= i;
> }
> ```
>
> In your tab Fragment (which is a child of `TabsTabsSwipeFragment`):
>
> ```
>    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
>         ((mainActivity) getSupportActivity()).setTagFragmentId(this
>                 .getId());
>     }
> ```

Reference: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Addon:-Slider

Answer (score 7):

For getting the current active and visible Fragment, it's my understanding that HoloEverywhere uses Android's Support Library. Try something similar to "[get currently displayed fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294603/get-currently-displayed-fragment)."

```
public Fragment getActiveFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

That said, when using ActionBar tabs this may get complicated because two or more Fragments can be visible at any given time (i.e. swiping between the two). You may wish to give your Fragments tags and search for them manually by querying the `isVisible` method.

Now for disabling swiping, I have no idea what TabsTabsSwipeFragment is but you can get a reference to any Fragment by querying their tag from the Fragment manager, of if you really want by looping through all Fragments and comparing the class (`Object.getClass`). Disabling a ViewPager from being swiped can be accomplished by something similar to "[How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)"

```
package com.yourcompany;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean swipeable = true;

    public SwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setSwipeable(boolean swipe) {
        this.swipeable = swipe;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return (swipeable) super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return (swipeable) super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() always return 0

Comment: How are you adding Fragments? Are you giving them tags? Try calling `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after `commit()`. It's difficult to help without any source code.

Comment: fragments are created by slider: sliderMenu = addonSlider().obtainDefaultSliderMenu(R.layout.menu);
  sliderMenu.add("tab1",
    TabsTabsSwipeFragment.class, SliderMenu.BLUE);
  sliderMenu.add("tab2", Fragment2.class,
    SliderMenu.GREEN);  As u see i cant tag the fragment

Comment: Based on the source code of SliderMenu, I'm not sure a way is easily provided. You can try calling the `executePendingTransactions` method in the Activity's `onPostCreate` method but it doesn't look like HoloEverywhere provides such functionality. If you cannot get this to work, try to maintain your own list of Fragments as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi