# Main Activity get data from 2 fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have read through some posts on here regarding activity-fragment communication but my problem is unique; i will try state it as clear as possible for you to understand. In my app there is a Mainactivity and 2 fragments(we call these fragment1 and fragment2) which are in sliding tab layout. The main activity contains a navigation drawer, and fragment1 contains a TextView and other fragment2 contains EditText. Heres problem now, there option on drawer called share:- when it is clicked, i want to access string value in Textview of Fragment1 or value in EditText of Fragment2; depends on which fragment is active in tablayout. now i want to pass string value to text message argument of intent in order for it to be shared with whatever client the user chooses.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

     //Inside the onNavigationItemSelected
        String value = " ";
        Fragment currentFragment= getActiveFragment();

        if(currentFragment instanceof SpeechToText){
            value = ((SpeechToText)currentFragment).getText1();
        }else if(currentFragment instanceof TTS){
            //This one has the edittext
            value = ((TTS)currentFragment).getText2();
        }
//Then create the intent
//Intent shareIntent ...
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,value);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Message");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
    }
```

I have this function from the post you provided to return current active fragment in tab layout.

```
    public Fragment getActiveFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    } String tag =    getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

I have implementation for methodForGettingTextViewValue() in SpeechToText fragment which is Fragment1:
    public String getText1()
    {
        return resultTEXT.getText().toString();
        }

I have implementation for methodForGettingEditTextValue() in TTS fragment which is Fragment2
       public String getText2()
    {
        return  return editText.getText().toString();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the active fragment in your tab layout, then check the class of the fragment, and depending on which one it is, call the method that would return either the content of the `TextView` or that of the `EditText`.

To keep track of the current fragment, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926763/how-to-get-currently-visible-fragment-from-activity-when-using-holoeverywhere-sl).

Once you have that part sorted, inside the `onNavigationItemSelected` implementation, before you create the `Intent` you'd do something like this, assuming `currentFragment` is being updated, and that you've implement the needed methods in each of the two fragments:

```
//Inside the onNavigationItemSelected
String value = "";
if(currentFragment instanceof MyCustomFragment1){
    value = ((MyCustomFragment1)currentFragment).methodForGettingTextViewValue();
}else if(currentFragment instanceof MyCustomFragment2){
    //This one has the edittext
    value = ((MyCustomFragment2)currentFragment).methodForGettingEditTextValue();
}
//Then create the intent
//Intent shareIntent ...
```

In case it's not clear enough, let me insist that you'd need to implement `methodForGettingEditTextValue` and `methodForGettingTextViewValue`. The method should access the view by id, get the value and return it.

Comment: I have updated my post and it works now, thank u so much for providing the algorithm, I had to fix up code myself to get it to work but ur answer helped me alot and that post u provided,