# PreferencesActivity with Fragment - how to determine user enter/left

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-preferences

I want to determine if the user is in settings or not. I have an `PreferencesActivity` and a `SettingsFragment`.

The first approach was to use the `onResume` and `onPause` methods of the `PreferencesActivity` to do that. The problem is that if I click in the my settings (PreferencesActivity) on some subitem of settings (e.g. wlan settings), the onPause method will be called, but I'm still in the settings and haven't left them.

Are there some good solutions to detect, if the user joins or lefts completely the settings and not only the PreferencesActivity?

---

Another consideration would be to set the flag when calling from another activity, but then you have to do that in each activity which calls the settings.

And then there's the problem of how to determine when the user lefts the settings. I've tried to use the onBackPressed method of the PreferencesACtivity, but this is also called if I click on back at the SettingsFragment (settings sub menu) and go to the PreferencesActivity (settings main menu).

Comment: Have you tried using Fragment.isAdded() or Fragment.isInLayout()? Or the FragmentManager to see if it is in the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this. check if any of your fragment is still visible and accordingly go about it

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = YourActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
    //user is still in settings or sub-settings
}else{
     //do something else
}
```

Comment: I have to use your code in the PreferencesActivity which extends PreferenceActivity. So there is no getSupportFragmentManager(), only a getFragmentManager() but the getFragmentManager() does not have a method called getFragments()

Comment: like you said there is no getFragments() method for getFragmentManager(). Check this thread, I believe they have found a way around i.e., if you still haven't found any other way
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi