# How can I return this fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a (pre-written) Fragment, accessed as `R.layout.myFragment`. Since I have to pass a Fragment (also in pre-written code) to a FragmentPagerAdapter inside a ViewPager, I have tried to pass it as `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.myFragment)`, but it returned null, probably as it expects something in the form of `R.id.something`.
I found some answers here at SO - related to implementing Google Maps fragments - but those (I think) do not apply to my problem because I have to use a Fragment in a form of `R.layout.myFragment` and have no Parent/Container Fragments (or something similar, as far as I know) to use a FragmentTransaction.
The Fragment is expected to be returned in a ViewPager's FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem() override. How can I get that Fragment to pass it to return it?

Comment: Where is the code,Have you tired ?

Comment: please consider accepting an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions. Both of which involve iterating through all fragment to find the one you need.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi) by [didi_X8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033547/5935255), you can use the onAttachFragment method of the Activity class to create a list of all the attached fragments and later iterate through them:

```
List<WeakReference<Fragment>> fragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    fragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}

public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : fragList) {
    Fragment f = ref.get();
    if(f != null) {
        if(f.isVisible()) {
            ret.add(f);
        }
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

Another solution [as explained by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20374738/5935255) would be to use the support library and take advantage of the getFragments method:

```
public List<Fragment> getVisibleFragments() {
List<Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
if (allFragments == null || allFragments.isEmpty()) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

List<Fragment> visibleFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
for (Fragment fragment : allFragments) {
    if (fragment.isVisible()) {
        visibleFragments.add(fragment);
    }
}
return visibleFragments;
}
```