# getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working with a viewpager and compiling API 23. I'm showing a compile error in my code for the following statement, but the project does compile.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

Furthermore, I cannot find this method in the android documentation for either the support fragment manager and the non-support one.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: The first comment to Michael's answer says it all... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102007/is-there-a-way-to-get-references-for-all-currently-active-fragments-in-an-activi `We shouldn't use this method. It is marked with @hide and was not supposed to be included with the support library jar. It should not be considered part of the exported API.` Since it was **hidden**, I guess that Google finally decided to remove that method.

Comment: Did you use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;?

Comment: That method has not been deprecated as of version 24.1.1 of the support library. What exactly is the error being displayed?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Cannot resolve method.  (Basically just getting a red underline under the method, but the project compiles.

Comment: @sonnv1368, yes, I did.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually did this to get a reference to all the fragments:

```
private List<WeakReference<Fragment>> mFragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    mFragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}

public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : mFragList) {
        Fragment f = ref.get();
        if(f != null) {
            if(f.isVisible()) {
                ret.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public Fragment findFragement(String tClass) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = getActiveFragments();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if (tClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")) {
            if (fragment instanceof ToggleFragment) {
                return fragment;

            }
        } else if (tClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Contacts")) {
            if (fragment instanceof ContactFragment) {
                return fragment;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much kristy! you are the best! Also , if you can explain what getactivefragments does, it will be awesome!

Comment: also for : @Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    mFragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}
wouldnt it cause duplicates when a screen is recreated or ft.replace() is used.

Comment: @MarissaNicholas I don't think it would create duplicates when the screen is recreated (like on rotate).  Maybe on ft.replace().

Comment: do you think something like this would prevent that from happening? : @Override 
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) { 
for (WeakReference<Fragment> reference : mFragList) { 
if (reference instanceOf WeakRefence<ThisFragment>) { 
return; 
} 
mFragList.add(fragment); 
} 
}