# Remove OLDEST commited back stack Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, fragmentmanager

I have a navigation drawer menu (with just a few items) that invokes switching fragments, something like this:

```
 FragmentTransaction trans = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(String.valueOf(item.Index)); // item.Index is clicked nav. drawer item index

    trans.commit();
```

Now, when the user navigates in the application using the drawer, the back stack keeps growing and growing. When there are many items in the stack (say > 30 or something like this), some amount of memory is being used, which I don't like, because there's a danger that at some point it'll reach the critical point and I'll get OOMException.

So is there any way to remove the OLDEST items from the back stack? I don't want to use `popBackStack()` (and similar) because it will delete the NEWEST item and I want to get rid of the first (oldest) items since the user won't probably remember where he/she was 10 navigations earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found some sort of a workaround so I'll answer my own question, maybe someone will find it useful.

Since there's no way of removing the oldest stack from `FragmentManager`, I've decided to thrown it away and go with my own 'back stack' implementation.

More details here:
http://stuffleftatparty.com/android-app-will-eat-its-entire-memory-by-design

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove first 10 fragments by following way

```
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null && getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 30) {
        Iterator itr = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().iterator();
        int index = 0;
        //REMOVE FIRST 10 fragments on Stack
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (index < 10) {
                itr.remove();
            }else {
                    break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm affraid it won't work since `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` is no longer available.

Comment: When you extend your activity with AppCompatActivity than it is available.

Comment: I meant we shouldn't use `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` because it's marked as hidden and internal:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772575/getsupportfragmentmanager-getfragments-deprecated

Also there's no `getFragments()` in the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

And finally, looking at `FragmentManager` sources it looks like there're some additional structures (`FragmentManager.BackStackEntry`) that should be removed as well. Removing only `Fragment`s will probably be too little.